# Compare Serial read data and analog read value

Tags: string, serial-port, compare, arduino, analog-digital-converter

I am going to send a input to Arduino through serial communication. That variable should be stored in a variable. That data which I send through serial communication should be compared to an analog input value and if both becomes equal, then some action should be performed.

The data sent to Arduino through serial communication is only sent once. So, the program should store the value and therefore compare with the analog input value. What should I use, String or string conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Your analog data using [analogRead()](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/analogRead) will be an [int](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Int) in the range of 0-1023 (though depending on your sensor, it could be much less than that but those are the min/max values). So your target value sent over the serial port can just be stored in an [int](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Int) variable using [parseInt()](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/ParseInt).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot- skinnyTod. it actually worked. the main problem i encountered was that parse int does not work in versions other than 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine the end of the string. If you were sending single character commands or byte values then you can simple Serial.read() the value into the "int". Where as I suspect your are sending text numbers e.g. "123" or a string of "1","2",3","\n".

Either char*(string) or String will work. But you have to build the "string" from the serial.read's and identify the end of the string. Hence noting the use of "\n". Or you can frame it to always expect the same number of characters. e.g. "0","2",3"

[see previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197097/arduino-how-read-string-from-serial) and [other](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38845/arduino-serial-read-to-int) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671810/arduino-string-to-int-gets-strange-values)